# isDisplayed always returns false for the specific element

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium to check if error message shown when user sent form with empty fields. Error message block is attached to the DOM all the time, but when there is no errors it has "display: none;" style attribute. So, when I push the "save" button, I check if this block visible this way:

```java
Assert.assertTrue("There is no validation error!", driver.findElement(By.id("validationModal")).isDisplayed());
```

And this works. But when I'm trying to check that messages in this block are showed, isDisplayed method always returns "false". When I use just this:

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("validationModal")).findElement(By.tagName("ul"))
            .findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Empty app name field')]"));
```

it goes fine, but it's wrong because it wouldn't throw an exception when this text will be not visible, but will be in page code. If I write this:

```java
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("validationModal")).findElement(By.tagName("ul"))
            .findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Empty app name field')]")).isDisplayed());
```

it always fails. And I don't really understand why and how I can check, that text of error message is shown, right way.

---

**UPD:**
I've found the source of problem. This string finds not element inside "validationModal" block, but inside  tag, which contains text we have to find.

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("validationModal")).findElement(By.tagName("ul"))
                .findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Empty app name field')]")).isDisplayed()
```

But I still not understand why it happens, because I specify the element where it should be searched for.

Comment: Could you share your html please?

Comment: I'm not sure, but looking on the page code I discovered, that content of error is not static, as I thought, so I guess this is the source of the problem, because of attaching content dynamically with the script.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to interact with some modal frame.

Generally to interact with modal element you should change driver context first.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ModelFrameTitle");
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement()
```

Find or check elements and then come back to main frame

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 Assert.assertTrue("Element is not displayed",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Empty app name field')]")).isDisplayed());
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in xpath.

Wrong string was:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Empty app name field')]"))
```

And right is:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Empty app name field')]"))
```